# Incompatibe Return Type error when implementing generic interface method

Tags: java, generics, javafx, return, return-type

I have a very simple interface:

```
public interface Evaluateable<T> {
    public T evaluate();
}
```

I am trying to implement the `evaluate()` method in another class:

```
public class NumberNode() implements Evaluateable {
    public double evaluate() { // Error with this method
        return 5.0;
    }
}
```

However apparently evaluate() has an 'incompatible return type', despite the interface method being generic. Am I constructing the generic method wrong -- what's happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use a primitive type as a generic type. `T` type erases to `Object`

Comment: @4castle that looks like an answer to me (with an explanation)...never mind, somebody else answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't specifying the type to the generic, and you can't use a primitive `double` (but you can use the `Double` *wrapper type*).

```
public class NumberNode() implements Evaluateable<Double> {
    public Double evaluate() {
        return 5.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Thank-you, I knew it'd be an easy fix.